# Python returns error NameError: name 'subject_t' is not defined

Tags: python

Python returns error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 29, in <module>
NameError: name 'subject_t' is not defined
```

code:

```
name = raw_input('Enter your name')

if name == 'Truxten':
    print "Hello Truxten"
    user_name = 'truxten'

if name == 'Hannah':
    print "Hello Hannah"
    user_name = hannah

if name == 'Matthew':
    print "Hello Matthew"
    user_name = matthew

if name == 'Jax':
    print "Hello Jax"
    user_name = jax

if name == 'Ellie':
    print "Hello Ellie"
    user_name = ellie

def t_subject():
    subject_t = raw_input('Enter the Subject')

if user_name == 'truxten':
    t_subject()

print subject_t
```

Comment: `subject_t` is defined inside the function `t_subject()`, thus it is out of scope when you try to print it.

Comment: Specifically, `subject_t` is a local variable of the function `t_subject()` and hence can't be accessed outside of it. You can make it so by adding a `global subject_t` statement.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `subject_t` is out of scope and indeed *isn't defined*.

The variable `subject_t` only exists inside the `t_subject()` function. So you can't display it.

You could use:

```
def t_subject():
     subject_t = raw_input('Enter the Subject')
     print subject_t
```

But I recommend, like with many functions you include a return statement:

```
subject = None

def t_subject():
     subject_t = raw_input('Enter the Subject')
     return subject_t

if name == 'truxten':
    subject = t_subject()

if subject is not None: 
    print subject
```

I think further research is involved on your behalf regarding [functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), variables, [scope](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces), and [classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#)... defiantly classes.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a value to variable `subject_t` in your `t_subject` function, you actually assign it to function's local scope. You have to define `subject_t` in global scope as follows:

```
subject_t = None

def t_subject():
    global subject_t
    subject_t = raw_input('Enter the Subject')
```

And you print `subject_t` unconditionally. If you use global scope approach, `subject_t` will contain `None` (or other value you had assigned to it globally), if `t_subject()` had never called.

Also, this is not directly related to question you've asked, but you are assigning **variables** named `hannah`, `matthew`, and not strings, like for `'truxten'`.

Comment: Suggesting that some-one should use Globals as the return value for a function is a really bad idea - even for a beginner. A far better solution would have been to show how to use return statements.

Comment: It was not clear whether author is beginner or just forced to use *that style*, so I've provided a solution to answer what was exactly asked, not what was he *possibly* tried to accomplish.

Comment: Fair enough - although I do hope no-one is ever forcing anyone to use Globals - shudder...